# Create array from iostream in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Im using groovy to capture the stdout of a command and I want to put the output into an array.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
def output = "/usr/local/bin/list-items".execute()    
output.text.toArray()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: An array of what? What is the output?

Comment: an array of the lines that would normally be printed to stdout

Comment: regions.text.eachLine allows me to iterate through the each line in the output

Answer (score 0):

Use `output.text.readLines()`. It returns `List<String>` you can convert it to array with `toArray(String[])`, so the full solution:

`output.text.readLines().toArray(String[])`